# Как из select получить dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Как из классического `select` сделать раскрывающийся список `dropdown`, а не выпадающий, как изначально? Т.е., чтобы раздвигал контент ниже, а не перекрывал [Фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/rb5p550t/)

```css
select {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из select классический раскрывающий список сделать вряд ли получится. Требуемый функционал не поддерживается.

Как вариант, поместить содержимое списка в отдельный тег (например `ul`) и с помощью JavaScript управлять его видимостью (свойство `style.display`). Примеры можно посмотреть [тут](http://www.cyberforum.ru/html/thread85965.html).

Также можно воспользоваться какой-нибудь библиотекой ([пример на jQuery](http://jemand.ru/raskryvayushhijsya-spisok-na-jquery/))

Comment: у меня просто фильтр предлагает выбор из вариантов (select, checkbox, label, color) - с какого легче переделать под выпадающий список?

Comment: ааа, понял как с `checkboxa` сделать! через `li` их оформить

Answer (score 0):

```
Возможно вам подойдет этот вариант.


<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#>Volvo</a>
    <a href="#>Saab</a>
    <a href="#>Mercedes</a>
    <a href="#">Audi</a>
 </div>
```

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}


window.onclick = function(event) {
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
  }
}
}
}
</script>



<style>
.dropbtn {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
padding: 16px;
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
overflow: auto;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
</style>
```

Comment: где-то у вас ошибка - список не раскрывается https://jsfiddle.net/rb5p550t/1/